# Executing mysql query as native query in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

I am new to Hibernate.  I am creating a web application using JSF, Spring and Hibernate.  I am trying to implement this query generated from the user filter using hibernate

```
select * from ( Select DATE_FORMAT(a.call_offered_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') As 'call_date', a.caller_id as 'Caller', DATE_FORMAT(a.call_offered_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') as  'Call Connected', DATE_FORMAT(a.call_disconnect_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') as 'Call Disconnected',a.channel_no as 'Channel', a.call_status as 'Call Status', (Case When  a.call_routed_to_agent=Null or  a.call_routed_to_agent='' then 'IVRS' Else call_routed_to_agent  End ) as 'Call Routed To', b.ddi,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.call_offered_time,a.call_disconnect_time) as 'Duration'from CallDetail a,ddi_details b Where a.call_reference_no =b.call_reference_no and a.call_offered_time Between '2006-01-01 00:00:00' And '2010-11-20 23:59:00') as t order by STR_TO_DATE(t.call_date,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s')
```

For this I tried the following code

```
Session session = null;
    // This step will read hibernate.cfg.xml and prepare hibernate for use
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = this.getSessionFactory(); 

    session =sessionFactory.openSession();



    //Create Select Clause HQL
     String SQL_QUERY ="select * from ( Select DATE_FORMAT(a.call_offered_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') As 'call_date', " +
                       "a.caller_id as 'Caller', DATE_FORMAT(a.call_offered_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') as  " +
                       "'Call Connected', DATE_FORMAT(a.call_disconnect_time,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s') as " +
                       "'Call Disconnected',a.channel_no as 'Channel', a.call_status as 'Call Status', " +
                       "(Case When  a.call_routed_to_agent=Null or  a.call_routed_to_agent='' then 'IVRS' " +
                       "Else call_routed_to_agent  End ) as 'Call Routed To', b.ddi," +
                       "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,a.call_offered_time,a.call_disconnect_time) as " +
                       "'Duration'from CallDetail a,iss_master.ddi_details b Where " +
                       "a.call_reference_no =b.call_reference_no and a.call_offered_time Between " +
                       "'2006-01-01 00:00:00' And '2010-11-20 23:59:00') as t order by STR_TO_DATE(t.call_date,'%d %b %Y %k:%i:%s')";

     System.out.println(SQL_QUERY);

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY).addEntity(InboundCallDetail.class);

    List result = query.list();
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.address.InboundCallDetail
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:580)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:335)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:376)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:171)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:136)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
at com.address.AddressDAOImpl.getDetails(AddressDAOImpl.java:102)
at com.address.AddressBean.getDetail(AddressBean.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:614)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1145)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:77)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:983)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:928)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please correct my mistake or suggest any alternate ways.

Thanks in advance,

P.S  This is a report application so the 'where' condition in the query is generated by the user through the filter.

**Update**
Sorry for being late!
Since I created the application using Spring with Hibernate I did not create hibernate-config.xml instead I furnished the details in application-context.xml

My application-context.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<!-- DataSource Definition -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <!-- MySQL Database -->
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate?characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>sa</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory Definition -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>
                com/address/Address.hbm.xml
            </value>                
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">
                true
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Spring Data Access Exception Translator Definition -->
<bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Template Definition -->
<bean id="hibernateTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcExceptionTranslator">
        <ref bean="jdbcExceptionTranslator" />
    </property>
</bean> 



<bean id="dao" class="com.address.AddressDAOImpl">  
<property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <ref bean="hibernateTemplate" />
    </property>                 
</bean>
<bean id="addressBean"
    class="com.address.AddressBean">
    <property name="dao">
        <ref local="dao" />
    </property>         
</bean>
<!-- ========================= Start of SERVICE DEFINITIONS =========================
-->

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

As @Shervin suggested I tried createNativeSQL(), I got the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.address.AddressDAOImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
... 31 more

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:698)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
at com.address.AddressDAOImpl.<init>(AddressDAOImpl.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
... 33 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:80)
at org.hibernate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:62)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:460)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:155)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:691)
... 42 more
```

My updated java code is as follows

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp");

em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(SQL_QUERY);
```

Please correct my problems.  Thanks for updates!!

**Update**

I tried as suggested by @ckuetbach  and I added

```
<value>
        com/address/InboundCallDetail.hbm.xml
    </value>
```

in the application-context.xml file

Now I am getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: column attribute may not be used together with <column> subelement
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: column attribute may not be used together with <column> subelement
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindColumns(HbmBinder.java:1075)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindColumnsOrFormula(HbmBinder.java:1547)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindSimpleValue(HbmBinder.java:1143)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2102)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.createClassProperties(HbmBinder.java:2060)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBinder.java:381)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:295)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:166)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:702)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:537)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:631)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
... 30 more
```

Please correct my mistake!

Comment: The exception `Unknown entity: com.address.InboundCallDetail` seems to be the result of a misconfiguration of hibernate. Did you you include that Entity to your Hibernate-configuration? Within an applicationserver the Entities will be found by the container, but not when you running your app standalone or as an junit-test.

Please post your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: @ckuetbach:  Sorry for being late. I have posted my application-context.xml.  Is this enough?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to execute mysql query as native query in Hibernate you can use `createNativeQuery()`

Comment: Sorry for being late.  Actually I tried to implement your suggestion.  Plz check my update!

Comment: I am not so familiar with Spring, but normally, if you inject the persistence context, you dont need to create entitymanager factory. So perhaps your mistake is there.

Comment: @Shervin:sorry I couldnt get you.  Can you make it more clear?  Please forgive me I am a beginner. It will be more helpful, if you tell what should I change in the code I posted.

Comment: I tried as you said and  removed the lines EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp");

em = emf.createEntityManager();
I am getting Nullpointer exception

Comment: ok, so I have no more ideas, other than looking in the stacktrace where it says `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: column attribute may not be used together with <column> subelement` This should hint you as to what is wrong.

Comment: this appears I have made some errors in hbm xml file.  Unable to find through Google! Should restart again from scratch. Sorry if any of my messages bothers you.  It will be more helpful for me if you suggest some tutorial regarding this!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to include a mapping to you Entity. You have to create and add mapping files for all of your Entities.

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>
            com/address/Address.hbm.xml
        </value>                
        <value>
            com/address/InboundCallDetail.hbm.xml
        </value>     
    </list>
</property>
```

The second problem seems to be, that you did not set the Hibernate Dialect `Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly`

Comment: regarding the second change.  What should I add in my application-context.xml file?